# Are the Q4 and Q5 transistors in reverse action mode?

Tags: transistors, bjt

[image]

Are the Q4 and Q5 transistors in reverse action mode ?

Comment: Since Vbe is +ve and both bases common to V+ (via R) it is called common base and is forward active

Answer (score 2):

With the inputs as shown the emitter of the transistor is at VCC. The base is pulled to VCC with a 1k resistor but the collector is connected to the base of Q3 that is lower in voltage than the base or emitter.

The transistor is in reverse mode. Its gain will be very low maybe 5-10 and it will have a low breakdown voltage.

The supply voltage is not shown but if it was 5V there would be about 3.5mA injected into the base resulting in 15-30mA from the emitter into the collector and injected into the base of Q3. This is consistent with the 30mA shown on the meter.

If the input switch was put in the other position with the emitter grounded the transistor would be in normal forward mode. This would saturate the transistor forcing the base of Q3 almost to ground.

Comment: The reverse mode is useful here: the saturation voltage is the lowest it can be.